# how to download remote file on server which require cookie

Tags: php, cookies

i want to download a file [in this link](http://www6.zippyshare.com/d/44950163/18/catalyst107.zip) on my free hosting server **(using PHP script/ftp or any other way)**, but this link require cookie value that is only on my browser...
and is that possible to insert cookie value of a external website in PHP script

Answer (score 1):

You can use php_curl for that:

http://www.php.net/manual/de/book.curl.php

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, "name=value; other=value");
```

Comment: thanks brother
but can you provide me simple example of this.. where to use this code and where i add cookie value and website from where i picked up the cookies